# Entity Framework (Code First) - Dynamically Building a Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, model, code-first

I have an assembly with classes my domains - "Domains.dll". I dynamically add to my DbContext Dbset load classes of assembly.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public MyContext() : base("DBConnection"){}

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Domains.dll");
       var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
       var list = assembly.GetTypes().OrderBy(i => i.GetType().Name);
       foreach (Type item in list)
       {
           entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(item)
     .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
       }

   }
}
```

Next, I create DataBase

```
context.Database.Create();
```

This works but with a problem for my domain. I have a class for the parent entity

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Entity
{
   public string FirstName {get ;set;}
   public string LastName {get ;set;}
}
```

If now I run a database   - table 'Person' is not create.It creates a table 'Entities' with fields Id, FirstName, LastName.

If I change the Person

```
public class Person 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get ;set;}
   public string LastName {get ;set;}
}
```

then created in the database two tables - 'Person' and  'Entities'. How do I use inheritance? How do I do it right?

Comment: I know this thread is very old! But did you get this problem running? **With auto-updating database?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `[Table("Person")]` Attribute, and I encourage you to take a look at that [Inheritance with EF Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx), It is a good post.

so to resume try this:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
[Table("Person")]
public class Person : Entity
{
   public string FirstName {get ;set;}
   public string LastName {get ;set;}
}
```