# Dynamic Table Creation Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I wanted to know if there is any way to create a dynamic table at the run time using entity framework. I know the schema of the table that I am going to create at compile time since I use Model-First approach of entity framework.For example I know the new table which will be created at the run time will have the specific format like below

```
Person
{
Id bigint,
Name nvarchar(max) ,
Age int
}
```

And when I call the method

```
public void CreateTable(string personName);
```

I wanted to create a new table which name is provided from the parameter like Person_hello that has the same columns (Id,Name,Age) . I have look up

[Dynamic Model Creation Using Code First](http://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/)

[MEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738537%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (which look closer to the answer but I cannot decide if it is the right one)

Comment: I have also seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138070/c-sharp-ef-4-1-create-table-dynamically-within-dbcontext) but it is using Code First Approach (according to my understanding)

Comment: Dont think EF supports dynamic tables - instead of hacking your way through - look into [TPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.5) and [TPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.6)