# SQL Server and Entity Framework don't save changes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following issue: I created a SQL Server `LocalDB` instance and created a simple table called `player`. Then I added an ADO.Net Entity Framework Data Model (database to code) and instantiated the POCO class `Player`.

Then I added the instance to the `DbContext`'s `Player` property and I executed the `SaveChanges()` method - with no effect at all.

Maybe I took the wrong SQL provider (cause there are 2 SQL Server providers: `localdb` and SQL Server)?

That are the properties of my `.mdf` file (the db):

```
Provider: .NET Framework-Datenanbieter für SQL Server
Type: Microsoft SQL-Server
Connection string: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MsSQLSample\MsSQLSample\myLocalDb.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

I created the database like this:

```
New Element --> Service-based Db.
```

Then I added a table and set the primary key as `Identity ad NOT Null` etc...

I don't know why but none of the instances I added to the contexts property was taken by the db.

```
using (var db = new PlayerContext()) 
{ 
    Table table = new Table() 
    { 
        IpAddress = "test";
    }; 

    db.Table.Add(table); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

**EDIT: Thats how I made a new localdb-instance**
[image: record_new_db]

**Thats how I made a new table:**
[image: record_new_table]

**Thats how I use the EntityFramework**
[image: new_entity_model]

Comment: Are any exceptions being raised on SaveChanges()?

Comment: Are you getting anything when you try to retrieve from the database? Just curious if you're hitting the database you think you are. I've had it before where I wound up looking at the wrong place, and they're all sitting there when I found the right database.

Comment: @krillgar, its strange: When I add new rows manually (not with code), I can receive them using my DbContext. But when I try to add new rows programmatically, it doesnt add that to the table

Comment: Your db file is overwritten each time you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are trying to add an row, not a new table, I might be wrong, but you already define the tables ether [code-first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx), [model first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424.aspx) or [database-first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/database-first-with-entity-framework.aspx).

```
using (var db = new PlayerContext()) 
{ 
    Player player= new Player() 
    { 
        IpAddress = "test";
    }; 
    var newRow = context.Set<Player>();
    newRow.Add(player); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
//sidenote: once saveChanges() occured, Id of the new player is saved in the 'player' object
```

If you really trying to add tables while running the application (on user input), I recommend you re-think your database design (ERD). If you are trying to do code-first Initialization, then [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138070/c-sharp-ef-4-1-create-table-dynamically-within-dbcontext) will get you started.

Comment: Sorry for that misunderstanding: I did not change the name of my Table so the generated POCO-Class is even called table, too. I use database-first and oft course only want to add New rows.

Comment: Was this the solution you were looking for then?

Comment: No i know the code but it doesnt apply thos on the DB.